# Import multiple Excel files to create 1 table in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have a few experience in using SQL Server 2012.

All I know to import a excel to database is like the following:

1. open SQL Server Management Studio
2. right click on the "table" folder -> Tasks -> Import Data
3. set data source to MS Excel.

It seems that only one Excel is entertained.

But I want to concatenate 6 Excel files (all with same column layouts) to form a single table in SQL Server.

P.S. No need to tell me to concatenate the Excel file manually by copy and paste because each individual Excel file has about ~50,000 records.

Any ideas / solutions by using sql scripts or any other programming methods?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just run the import several times - the first import will create the new table, for any subsequent import, you can tell the Import Wizard to **append** the imported rows to the existing table

Answer (score 0):

There's a range of ways to do this, but I'll give you the simplest that comes to mind without requiring any deep technical knowledge on your part.

Given that you're using the wizard, firstly on the 'Select Table Sources and Views' page, change the 'Destination' to be the name of the table you've previously created.

Then, under the 'Edit Mappings' menu when selecting your sheets, ensure you have 'Append rows to the destination table' selected, rather than Create/Delete. Within reason, this will achieve your goal.

There is a risk in flat file loading like this that SQL Server will create your table with unsuitable types (i.e. a Column is a text column, but only contained numbers on the first file - so the column was created as an INT and wont accept any other files). You'll need to create the tables from scratch again with the right structure or work with the mappings page to do this work.

Another way for the semi-technical type is as long as the data is equivelent between files, you can simply do your imports into a series of seperate tables:

- Table1
- Table2
- Table3
- ...

Then do a

```
 INSERT INTO Table1
   SELECT * FROM Table2 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT * FROM Table3 
   ... Add tables here
```

You can then use DROP TABLE to remove the extras.